# StageVideo on Android Air 3.1 no video but audio?

Tags: flash, actionscript, mobile, air

I got StageVideo to work correctly on Iphone 4S.

I wanted to try it on my Google Nexus S.

I got the audio but not the video.

Now on desktop if StageVideo is not available it just doesn't work.

But am getting Audio which leads me to believe that it should be possible.

Any ideas? I tried packaging it using CPU/GPU and auto.

The phone has AIR 3.1 installed.

Thanks

Comment: I've got same issue, have you resolved it somehow?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I gave up pending other projects let me know if you find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, it seems to be a bug in the AIR or device dependent problem. I tried to fall back to normal video in case of Nexus7 and it works fine so far. Performance is not affected because Nexus7 is quite powerful device :)

Btw. Adobe registers many bugs regarding AIR and video playback, let's hope they'll fix it sometimes :)